# Viewpager moves from current page to default fragment page, after calling implicient intent

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

While calling implicient intent from viewpager fragment ,  current fragment of viewpager  changes to default fragment.
Used mvvm architecture, with single fragment in single activity. View pager is inside fragment.

Any suggestion  would be helpful.

Comment: Issue solved by using architectural component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by using architectural component .